# To stay logged in when app get purged from memory

Tags: iphone

Big question - my programmer is saying no but i want another opinion.
I have an  iPhone app (in construction). It connects to a server.
The user logs in  but too often when the app comes out of background another log-in (email address and Pin Number) is required rather than the simple pin number. Is there a way to keep the email address either 1/ in memory or 2/somewhere else on the phone.
I notice with the Facebook app (you may have heard of them)  they just stay logged in regardless.
is this possible too for an individual player?
Thanks in advance

Joe

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. Just save the username in the `NSUserDefaults` and the pin in the keychain.
Then we the apps starts just check if those values are set and log the user in.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried learn programming but have only become convinced you guys are from another planet. thanks again

Comment: Some of us are, just don't tell everyone